# How to extract an SSL/TLS message using scapy and python?

Tags: python, ssl, networking, scapy

I'm trying to read a TLS message. Specifically, the one with the certificate details (handshake_type = 11). What I'm doing is first checking that the message contains `Raw`. If so, I'm extracting the payload like so: `b = bytes(pkt[Raw].load)`. Next, I'm checking that *the first* byte is `0x16` and the following two bytes need to be a proper TLS version.

The problem is that this message doesn't pass these conditions. WireShark is showing me that `\x16\x03\x03` are the bytes at position `0000` (picture is attached), but I guess it is done for convenience.

So is my assumption that the payload MUST start with `0x16` wrong?

P.S
I don't want to use `scapy-ssl_tls` library.

[image]

**EDIT**
This is the code:

```
def handle_tls_packet(pkt):
    if pkt.haslayer(Raw):
        b = bytes(pkt[Raw].load)

        if b[0] == 0x16:
            version =  int.from_bytes(b[1:3], 'big')
            message_len = int.from_bytes(b[3:5], 'big')
            handshake_type = b[5]
            handshake_length = int.from_bytes(b[6:9], 'big')

            print("v = ", version, " len = ", message_len, " htype =", handshake_type
            , "hlen =", handshake_length)

            if handshake_type == 11:
                # never happens - Why?
                certs_len = int.from_bytes(b[7:11], 'big')
```

**EDIT2:**
As suggested by **Cukic0d**, I used `load_layer("ssl")`.

Apparently, `pkt[TLS].msg` is a list (to hold multiple TLS messages in one packet?). Anyways, I printed the type of every such message like so:

```
def handle_tls_packet(pkt):
    for tls_msg in pkt[TLS].msg:
        print(type(tls_msg))
```

I expected to see a `TLSCertificate` object, yet such object is never seen.
Why?

**EDIT3:**
I'm willing to use `scapy-ssl_tls` if that would make life easier.

Comment: In the first EDIT, have you figured out why your code is not working? I want to follow a similar pattern as what you did in your code (not depending on any scapy packages for ssl tls).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to play with TLS handshake, enable TLS on scapy using `load_layer("tls")`.

That enables the TLS module, which supports handshake (requires scapy >= 2.4.0). Scapy will then correctly dissect TLS handshake/key... packets

You should first try

```
load_layer("tls")
packets = sniff(prn=lambda x:x.summary(), lfilter=lambda x: TLS in x)
```

And if you're using Scapy 2.4.4+, for better consistency you can even use

```
sniff([...], session=TLSSession)
```

Have a look on how the packets are built:

Example:
[image: Screenshot]

There is also a quite fancy guide here: https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/notebooks/tls/notebook2_tls_protected.ipynb

So summarize:
[image: Screenshot 2]

You will find each packet when using `load_layer("tls")`.

Note that there are a lot of packets and that TLSCertificate will only appear once. `msg` is a list because many informations can be contained in a single TLS packet

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot tomorrow!

Comment: Okay, so I used it but interestingly I never see `TLSCertificate` msg. I'll edit my question for my details.

Comment: I've updated my answer. There are a lot of packets, TLSCertificate will only appear once.

Comment: The code I attached in my post should handle all the messages, right? Yet, I never see `TLSCertificate` - Not even once. Maybe it's part of some `TLSServerHello` message?

Comment: I used the `ls()` function and found the following data:
`msg        : _TLSMsgListField                    = [<Raw  load='\x0b\x00\x0b\x88\x00\x0b\x85\x00\x06\xe70\x82\x06\xe30\x82\x05\xcb\xa0\x03\x02\x01\x02\x02\x10\x05,\xd1\xe8\xf9\x82\x04R0m~\x1f&\xea\xb0\x970\r\x06\t*\x86H\x86\xf7\r\x01\x01\x0b\x05\x000M1\x0b0\t\x06\x03U\x04\x06\x13\x02US1\x150\x13\x06\x03U\x04\n\x13\x0cDigiCert Inc1\'0%\x06\x03U\x04\x03\x13\x1eDigiCert SHA2 Secure Server`

Comment: It seems like scapy sees it as a Raw message.

Comment: Basically, it could be a session for any sites that uses https. It's done mainly for educational purposes

Comment: I found that the certificate name is within the Server Hello message, for some unknown reason. Here: https://imgur.com/rVQsxwb