# Cannot read tls section even after calling load_layer('tls') in scapy

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, scapy

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423507/how-to-extract-an-ssl-tls-message-using-scapy-and-python) question explains how to read the TLS section of a packet using scapy.

However, my program is not able to read it. All it returns is a bunch of hexadecimal characters

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> load_layer('tls')
>>> cap = rdpcap('tls.pcap')
>>> p1=cap[0]
>>> p1
<Ether  dst=14:cc:20:51:33:ea src=f4:f2:6d:93:51:f1 type=0x800 |<IP  version=4 ihl=5 tos=0x0 len=146 id=62970 flags=DF frag=0 ttl=64 proto=tcp chksum=0x50a0 src=192.168.1.143 dst=54.254.250.149 |<TCP  sport=49335 dport=50443 seq=549695462 ack=200962336 dataofs=5 reserved=0 flags=PA window=4380 chksum=0xb0ac urgptr=0 |<Raw  load="\x17\x03\x01\x00 \xf2\x10\xfd\x95N'\xf2\xaf\x99tp\x93\xbc\xe9\x81w\x91\x1b\xe0\xc9M:\x9a!]\xb0!\xae\xd2\x86\xb0>\x17\x03\x01\x00@d>\x0b\xee\xf0\xab\xded\x02E)\x0e0\xbb\xe6\x82uU\xb22\x87\xd6\xe4n[\x1d\x18\xe8\xd6\x1c\x00N_C\xe6\xdd\xbe\x89@6p\xd9\xaf\x19\xb3s\x07H\xdeF\x88\xdar\x0f\x8a\n!4\xeb\xd3F\xefgH" |>>>>
```

I want to get the tls record version, tls record length and the tls record content type.

This is screenshot of the packet opened in wireshark.
[image]

Can somepne please show me what I am doing wrong and how to read the tls content properly?

I am using Python3.6, and thus am not able to use stable `scapy-ssl_tls`, which is currently limited to Python 2.

Comment: Per the referenced [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51423507/how-to-extract-an-ssl-tls-message-using-scapy-and-python), are you using [scapy-ssl_tls](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls)?

Comment: No. scapy-ssl tls cannot be used with Python3. I am using scapy

Comment: @Nht_e0 now it can be used with py3 https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls/tree/py3compat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are so close. You just need to use `TLS(pkt.load)`.

#### Download a TLS Capture

For this example, use this [tls capture](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=13973&name=DNS-over-TLS.pcapng) from Wireshark's Bugzilla.

We can see that packet 4 is the TLS Client Hello:

```sh
tshark -r DNS-over-TLS.pcapng -Y "frame.number==4"
    4   0.122267 133.93.28.45 → li280-151.members.linode.com TLSv1  384 Client 
Hello 00:00:5e:00:01:18 ← 48:d7:05:df:86:0b
```

#### Load with Scapy

Make sure that you have the cryptography library installed, as it's required for loading TLS captures.

```py
>>> import cryptography
>>> # No errors
```

Reproducing what you have so far with this capture:

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> load_layer('tls')
>>> cap = rdpcap('DNS-over-TLS.pcapng')
>>> tls_client_hello=cap[3] # Wireshark numbers packets starting at 1, scapy at 0
>>> tls_client_hello
<Ether  dst=14:cc:20:51:33:ea src=f4:f2:6d:93:51:f1 type=0x800 |<IP  version=4 
ihl=5 tos=0x0 len=146 id=62970 flags=DF frag=0 ttl=64 proto=tcp chksum=0x50a0 
src=192.168.1.143 dst=54.254.250.149 |<TCP  sport=49335 dport=50443 seq=549695462 
ack=200962336 dataofs=5 reserved=0 flags=PA window=4380 chksum=0xb0ac urgptr=0 |
<Raw  load="\x17\x03\x01\x00 
\xf2\x10\xfd\x95N'\xf2\xaf\x99tp\x93\xbc\xe9\x81w\x91\x1b\xe0\xc9M:\x9a!]\xb0!\xa
e\xd2\x86\xb0>\x17\x03\x01\x00@d>\x0b\xee\xf0\xab\xded\x02E)\x0e0\xbb\xe6\x82uU\x
b22\x87\xd6\xe4n[\x1d\x18\xe8\xd6\x1c\x00N_C\xe6\xdd\xbe\x89@6p\xd9\xaf\x19\xb3s\
x07H\xdeF\x88\xdar\x0f\x8a\n!4\xeb\xd3F\xefgH" |>>>>
```

Note that the part that we want to view is called `Raw  load`. To access this part of the packet, you use `tls_client_hello.load`. Keep in mind that TLS will take a bytes object that contains the data, but not an entire packet.

```py
>>> TLS(tls_client_hello.load)
<TLS  type=handshake version=TLS 1.0 len=313 iv=b'' msg=[<TLSClientHello  
msgtype=client_hello msglen=309 version=TLS 1.2 gmt_unix_time=Tue, 18 May 2077 
23:20:52 +0000 (3388605652) 
random_bytes=d6d533aca04dca42db8b123b0a143dcd580079147122e4de095c15cf sidlen=0 
sid='' cipherslen=182 ciphers=[TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 
< TLS output truncated ... >
```

#### Further Reading

I highly recommend looking at [Scapy TLS Notebooks](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/notebooks/tls) that do a good job of documenting scapy+TLS usage.